# sql like query slow if using declare parameter but fast if not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-like, performance

SQL 2008:
This is slow (takes 1 1/2 minutes):

```
declare @p1 varchar(50)
set @p1 = '976j%'
select * from invsearch_query where comparepnfwd like @p1
```

This takes less than a second:

```
select * from invsearch_query where comparepnfwd like '976j%'
```

Why???

Comment: Take a look at the query execution plans (or post them here)

Comment: Try casting your literal to see if that makes any difference (`CAST('976j%' AS VARCHAR(50))`). Also, take a look at the execution plan to see the differences.

Comment: comparepnfwd is a varchar(50)

Comment: TAKES LESS THAN A SECOND: select * from invsearch_query where comparepnfwd like cast('976j%' as varchar(50))

Comment: @Rodney - And if you look at the plans does the fast one with the hardcoded literal do a non clustered index seek and key lookups and the slow one a clustered index scan? (BTW: If you are not sure how to see the plans select the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option on the "Query" menu in SSMS then execute your queries as normal, the Execution Plan tab will appear next to the Results and Messages Tabs.)

Comment: @Martin, yes you are right, the slow one was doing a clustered index scan on the main table (yes, invsearch_query was a view), and the fast one did index seeks and keylookups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would imagine that you must have a non covering index with leading column `comparepnfwd`  that is used by the literal query but not by the query with the variable.

You can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get SQL Server to recompile the plan taking into account the actual variable value.

Comment: option (recompile) made the 1st query as fast as the 2nd query. thanks.